# Control image placement on JTextPane

Tags: jtextpane, imageicon

I am able to add ImageIcons to a JTextPane, but when I add them they show up in the center of the JTextPane. I can't find a way to control where they are placed on the JTextPane. Can someone please help me with this?

This method is making the JTextPane:

```
private void loadTextPanel(JPanel contentPane) {
    chatLogPanel = new JPanel();
    chatLogPanel.setLayout(null);
    EmptyBorder eb = new EmptyBorder(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

    DefaultStyledDocument document = new DefaultStyledDocument();
    chatLog = new JTextPane(document);
    chatLog.setEditorKit(new WrapEditorKit());
    chatLog.setBorder(eb);
    chatLog.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
    chatLogScrollPane = new JScrollPane(chatLog);

    addComponent(chatLogPanel, chatLogScrollPane, 0, 0, 500, 240);
    addComponent(contentPane, chatLogPanel, 0, 40, 500, 240);
}
```

This is the code I'm using to add a string to the Panel:

```
private static void appendToChatLog(JTextPane tp, String msg, Color c) {
    chatLog.setEditable(true);
    StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
    AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, c);

    aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontFamily, "Lucida Console");
    aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.Alignment, Integer.valueOf(3));

    int len = tp.getDocument().getLength();
    tp.setCaretPosition(len);
    tp.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
    tp.replaceSelection(msg);
    chatLog.setEditable(false);
}
```

And this is what I'm currently using to add the image to the JTextPane:

```
BufferedImage image = generateBufferedImage(message.getImage());
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(image);

StyleContext context = new StyleContext();
StyledDocument document = (StyledDocument) chatLog.getDocument();

Style labelStyle = context.getStyle(StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE);

JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
StyleConstants.setComponent(labelStyle, label);

try {
    document.insertString(document.getLength(), "Ignored", labelStyle);
} catch (BadLocationException badLocationException) {
    badLocationException.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Add your current code, add java tag, break up sentences and maybe somehow show current ouput if code not sufficient to make this clear. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To insert a component to a JTextPane, and display it like a character, use the [insertComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html#insertComponent%28java.awt.Component%29) method.

To insert an Icon instead, use the [insertIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html#insertIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29) method.

Quite intuitive isn't it ;)